# Saving data to a Django Model from views.py

Tags: django

I have to save some data to a model in my database.

The data was sent to `views.py` from the client using ajax, was formatted in `views.py` and now needs to be saved. My problem is, I don't know how to create an instance of the form without a form contained in `request.POST`.

How do I create the `ModelForm` in `views.py` and populate it with data when I don't have anything in `request.POST` to start the form off with?

Here is the model:

```
class CompleteBallot(models.Model):
    ElectionID = models.ForeignKey(Election, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Vote = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Here is the form:

```
class SubmitBallotForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CompleteBallot
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can you please post the model that you are wanting to create an instance of?

Comment: There are a few odd things in your question. What is in your Ajax request if not a POST? Why does that view not have a `request.POST`? And if you really haven't got one for reasons I don't understand, why cannot you simply instantiate the model instance directly, like you would any other object, then save it - why do you need a form?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The ajax request is a POST, but I was under the impression that the form could only be created if the data was sent through the normal rendering of a form in the template and the submission of the data that way, not manually using ajax. I'm not sure how to go about instantiating the model directly and saving it - can you post this as a solution please? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that, a POST is a POST. And even if it's not in the right format for whatever reason, a form just wants a dictionary, it doesn't have to come directly from the POST. Finally, instantiating objects directly is covered in [the second part of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you, the link helped solve it. I don't know what made me think I needed a form!

Answer (score 0):

Your form would look like this:

```
class SubmitBallotForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CompleteBallot
        fields = ''
```

And your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = SubmitBallotForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.ElectionID = *INSERT AJAX DATA HERE*
        instance.Vote = *INSERT AJAX DATA HERE*
```

Give that a go

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but the `if` statement is not being triggered so the form doesn't get as far as being saved. What do you suggest?